# Notice: Undefined index: userid in... PHP not sending hidden input id

Tags: php, mysql

I have searched for a solution to my problem but have so far failed to come across a working solution.

I am trying to update a MySQL table using PHP but I keep getting the Error Undefined index: userid.

Below is all the code for my editUsers.php page. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
confirm_is_admin();

$sessionid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users JOIN users_in_roles ON users.id = users_in_roles.user_id WHERE users.id != $sessionid");

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$deleteid = $_GET['id'];

$deletequery = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id =?";

$deletestatement = $db->prepare($deletequery);
$deletestatement->bind_param('d', $deleteid);
$deletestatement->execute();
$deletestatement->store_result();

$deletesuccessful = $deletestatement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
if($deletesuccessful){
    $userid = $deletestatement->delete_id;

    $deleteRoleQuery = "DELETE FROM users_in_roles WHERE id=?";

    $deleterolestatement = $db->prepare($deleteRoleQuery);
    $deleterolestatement->bind_param('d', $userid);
    $deleterolestatement->execute();
    $deleterolestatement->close();

    header('location: editUsers.php');
} else{
    echo "Failed";
}
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['update'])){
$updateid = $_REQUEST['id'];
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$userrole = $_REQUEST['roleid'];
$userpassword = $_REQUEST['password'];

$updatequery = "UPDATE users SET username=?, password=SHA(?) WHERE id =?";

$updatestatement = $db->prepare($updatequery);
$updatestatement->bind_param('ssd', $username, $password, $updateid);
$updatestatement->execute();
$updatestatement->store_result();

$updateSuccessful = $updatestatement->affected_rows == 1 ? true : false;
if($updateSuccessful){
    $userid = $updatestatement->update_id;

    $updateRoleQuery = "UPDATE users_in_roles SET role_id=? WHERE id=?";

    $updaterolestatement = $db->prepare($updateRoleQuery);
    $updaterolestatement->bind_param('dd', $userrole, $userid);
    $updaterolestatement->execute();
    $updaterolestatement->close();

    header('location: editUsers.php');
}
else {
    echo "Failed";
}

}


?>


<div id="container">
<?php
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if ($row_count == 0) {
            echo '<p style="color:red">No User details available</p>';
        } elseif ($query) {
            while($users = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                $user_id = $users['id'];
                $userrole = $users['role_id'];
                $username = $users['username'];

                echo '<div class="admin">';
                echo '<form method="post" action="editUsers.php"';
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$user_id.'" />';
                echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="'.$username.'" /><br>';
                echo 'User Role: <input type="text" name="roleid" value="'.$userrole.'" /><br>(1 = admin, 2 = user)<br>';
                echo 'Password: <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br>';
                echo '<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />';
                echo '<br><br></form></div>';
            }
        }else {
             die('There was a problem with the query: ' .$query->error);             
         } 
         mysqli_free_result($query); 

?>
</div>
```

Comment: `echo '<form method="post" action="editUsers.php"';` is going to generate an invalid `form` element.

Comment: I fixed the form element by adding a > at the end of it. I didn't notice I had missed it. Although I closed it, it still isn't working.

Comment: is the error in this line `if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$deleteid = $_GET['id'];`

Comment: Yes that is where I am getting the error

Comment: how you are getting the value for `$_POST['delete']` `$_GET['id']` my question may seems dumb, but please reply

Comment: @user2860957 It should be posting when I click one of my submit buttons in my form. The id field is filled out in a hidden input. Here it is - echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$user_id.'" />';

Comment: you are defying the logic with this code, first of your problem can simply be solved, by removing the isset deletepost and turning get id to post id, as you are using post method in the form, so you only going to have post, you dont have delete in the form so you have to delete it, or if you insist on doing the deletation by get request, simply change form action, to "edituser.php?id=$user_id" and you are done, but if you solve this problem you will create another problem, that's why I said you are defying logic with this approach, ....... read the below comment as space is finish..........

Comment: ......(read the above comment first); well do one thing, tell me what you are trying to do, i have idea what you are trying to do, but want to be sure, and also tell me how you want to do it, just edit your question and let me know, i will post the solution, the reason i said edit your question, because what you are trying to do is not that complicated, if i dont have a time, some one else will post the solution for you, i did not know how to put it mildly that's why said you are defying logic, the way you wrote the code and what you are trying to achieve, dont mind please

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, undefined index usually refers to a hash array expression where you tried to get a key that doesn't currently exist in the hash array.

I see two cases where you are trying to get a key 'userid' that might be causing this error (it would help if you noted which code line is reported with the error).

```
$sessionid = $_SESSION['userid'];
```

You might not have a 'userid' key in your session data. You should check if that key is set before you try to read it.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$deleteid = $_GET['userid'];
```

This is another case where the 'userid' key might not be set in your $_GET superglobal. You should check if it is set before reading it.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: userid in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Big Mike/editUsers.php on line 13 - this is the error I get when I try to delete a user.

Comment: and when I try to update my users details it just fails.

Comment: I have edited my code above to change the posted userid to id. Also, my $_SESSION['userid'] is saved in my another PHP file and returns the id of the user that is logged in. This doesn't seem to be causing any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'userid' index your error refers to is the one in the $_SESSION superglobal, and the reason it is not set is that you are not calling session_start() to start/resume a session.